# How to post process the snapshot native heap exported from Android DDMS?

Tags: android, c++, memory-leaks, ddms, android-testing

I am doing a set of operations on my app repeatedly and checking for memory leaks. I am exporting the heap data from the DDMS snapshots. How do I post process these data and identify the memory leaks along with the call stack ? I tried MAT , but its for JAVA, I want for native heap data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native heap data in the HPROF file from DDMS. It is the Dalvik heap.

You will need to find out if there is some solution for dumping a native heap and inspecting it. I am not aware of one, but I have not gone looking for one, either.